# Reverse preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, generator

I have regex like this:

```
^page/(?P<id>\d+)-(?P<slug>[^\.]+)\.html$
```

and an array:

```
$args = array(
    'id' => 5,
    'slug' => 'my-first-article'
);
```

I would like to have function:

```
my_function($regex, $args)
```

which will return this result:

```
page/5-my-first-article.html
```

How can this be achieved?

Something like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex to get from an array to a string where some items from the array are concatenated with other text?

Comment: What do you mean by "get this?"  In what context?

Comment: Because I use the regex for matching URL. And I would make function to create URL from this regex again.

Comment: you want make a url with array data `$args` input?

Comment: yes, url from data from $args formatted to match regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting challenge, I coded something that works for this sample, note that you need PHP 5.3+ for this code to work:

```
$regex = '^page/(?P<id>\d+)-(?P<slug>[\.]+)\.html$';
$args = array(
    'id' => 5,
    'slug' => 'my-first-article'
);

$result = preg_replace_callback('#\(\?P<(\w+)>[^\)]+\)#', function($m)use($args){
    if(array_key_exists($m[1], $args)){
        return $args[$m[1]];
    }
}, $regex);

$result = preg_replace(array('#^\^|\$$#', '#\\\\.#'), array('', '.'), $result); // To remove ^ and $ and replace \. with .
echo $result;
```

**Output:** `page/5-my-first-article.html`

**[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a9vb5W)**.