# Regex to string with parameters

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression, and i would like to write string with it. Is it possible ?
As said in comments, i search a way to do a "reverse regex".

```
$expression = "#^/foo(-([a-z]+))?.html#";
echo what_i_search(array()); // /foo.html
echo what_i_search(array(Null, 'bar')); // /foo-bar.html
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague. But as I see it, you want something like "reverse regex". You might want to check two of my previous answers [**1**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498200) or [**2**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619330)

Comment: @HamZa It's exactly what i'm searching.

Comment: You want a templating engine, basically.