# Regex switch replacement and pattern

Tags: php, regex

Say I have a (user-configurable) regular expression like this:

```
$pattern = "something/([a-z]+)";
$replacement = "somethingelse/$1/foo";
```

Is it possible to "invert" the pattern and replacement?
Like this:

```
$pattern = "somethingelse/([a-z]+)/foo";
$replacement = "something/$1";
```

If it isn't possible to do this automatically, is it possible for certain sets of patterns? e.g. ones without nested capturing groups.

Comment: Just create an array of your patterns and replacements?

Comment: @hwnd I would like to compute the inverse automatically, instead of letting the user enter the inverse.

Comment: @dtech The idea is a bit vague. I've answered 2 questions about "reverse regex", maybe it's the same idea? Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498200/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619330). Otherwise, could you update the question to make it clearer?

Comment: @HamZa those 2 questions are indeed what I'm looking for